# Kohana 3: What are Validate::label and Validate::labels for?

Tags: php, validation, kohana-3

What are the `Validate::label` and `Validate::labels` functions for in Kohana 3? What are they meant to be used for?

Answer (score 1):

When you use the Validation class, the label() and labels() methods are to set the labels of the fields *for the error messages*.
Taken this code:

```
$user = ORM::Factory('user');

// Don't forget security, make sure you sanitize the $_POST data as needed
$user->values($_POST);

// Validate any other settings submitted
$extra_validation = Validation::factory(
    array('password' => Arr::get($_POST, 'password'),
        'password_confirm' => Arr::get($_POST, 'password_confirm'))
);

$extra_validation->rule('password_confirm', 'matches', array(':validation', 'password_confirm', 'password'))->label('password_confirm', 'Password confirm');

try 
{
    $user->save($extra_validation);
    // success
}
catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
{               
    $errors = $e->errors(TRUE);
    // failure
}
```

Loot at `->label('password_confirm', 'Password confirm')`, it sets how the field is named in the error message that you get when you do `$errors = $e->errors(TRUE);`.
I hope it's clear. If not, let me know.

Answer (score -1):

i guess to print out the validation errors inside the `<label>` tag

labels() sets many fields with an array and label() sets one field